# Entity Framework Core 7 database upon first initializing returns error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using the following command to import a database into Entity Framework Core 7:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -connection name=constring Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Output Models
```

Here is the connection string in my `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "constring": "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=Words;Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True"
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -connection name=constring Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Output Models
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpDbContextGenerator.TransformText()  
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.ProcessTemplate(ITextTransformation transformation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpModelGenerator.GenerateModel(IModel model, ModelCodeGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

EDIT-
In response to some of the comments, I am quite aware that entityframeworkcore is not a db. I was not importing data-I have another app that's doing that. I did resovlve this btw-I modified the entity classes, deleted the tables in the db, deleted all the previous migrations, added migrations, updated the database using the dotnet cli, and worked.

Comment: It is a known issue and is fixed in 7.0.3 coming in Fed 2023.

Comment: Entity Framework Core 7 is ***NOT*** a database - it's a database **access** layer - the database you're using might be SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL - or something else. You cannot import data **into** EF Core - you can import data into your RDBMS **using** EF Core

Comment: You are not importing data, you are trying to generate the code models for an existing Database. I advise you to make sure you can connect to your DB using SQL Management studio, to validate your server config (url etc)

Comment: @marc_s, technically, EF is more of a database abstraction layer and not so much a database access layer since it abstracts the programmer from the specifics of each DB provider (and the db providers, Sqlite, Oracle, etc, in turn provide data access capabilities directly to their specific engines).